# Printing a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have dispalyed a table in my web page i want to print it on the button click .My button is not working my code goes as follows.

```
<button id="button1">Print me</button>  
                        
    <table id="printTable" class="display responsive-table " style=" margin-bottom:50px; border-radius: 4px;"  >
    <thead>
    <tr >
    <th>Sl.No.</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
    
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    
    <script>
    function printData()
    {
        var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
        newWin= window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.print();
        newWin.close();
    }

    $('#button1').on('click',function(){
    printData();
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: You need to address the buttons ID with `$('#button1')`.

Comment: You have a typo. `$('button1')` should be `$('#button1')`

Comment: @MarkusZeller i have assigned that still it is not working.I have updated the code .

Comment: Code is still wrong! You need to use `#` in the onClick handler.

Comment: @MarkusZeller please may you flag this question as a typo?

Comment: @MarkusZeller still not working

Comment: @Gdfhj once you fix the typo, the button will work. Any new issue is a new question  and this one should be closed.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Flagged as requested.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not using jquery, do this :

```js
        function printData() {
            var divToPrint = document.getElementById("printTable");
            newWin = window.open("");
            newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
            newWin.print();
            newWin.close();
        }

        const btn = document.getElementById("button");
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => printData())
```

also you must close all tags (table, tbody..)

Comment: (you don't have to close the tags, but it may cause unintended effects)

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below code. I have comment out the newWin.close() function so you will see the result.

```
<button id="button">Print me</button>   
                        
    <table id="printTable" class="display responsive-table " style=" margin-bottom:50px; border-radius: 4px;"  >
    <thead>
    <tr >
    <th>Sl.No.</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th>Balance</th>
    
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
    
    <script>
    function printData()
    {
      
        var divToPrint=document.getElementById("printTable");
        newWin= window.open("");
        newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
        newWin.document.close();
        newWin.print();
        //newWin.close();
    }

    document.querySelector("#button").addEventListener("click", function(){
      printData();
    });
    
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't have closing table tag. There is an opening tbody tag instead.

Comment: I t has all the table tag.Here i have not mentioned that part of my coding

Comment: @Gdfhj no it's missing the closing table tag, but that shouldn't stop the button from working.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.